# What does 'it is love' mean?

Tags: phrases

I have heard many times from many people saying 'it is love' or  'French is love' or 'Baltimore is love'. What does it exactly mean? Shouldn't they use lovely instead.?

Comment: From what people do you hear this? Are they native speakers of English?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: I think then you should ask them what they mean. This is not an ordinary English expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor). A more concrete metaphor would be:

> George is a big teddy bear.

George is not literally a big teddy bear; he exhibits the qualities of a big teddy bear.  In the same way:

> Baltimore is love

means Baltimore exhibits the qualities of love.

(Having lived in Baltimore, I can't say I agree with this metaphor, except in that it exhibits insane jealous rages, tunnel vision, and a damn-the-consequences attitude).

Comment: Just kidding, Baltimore, you know I love you.

Comment: Have you heard people use this phrase metaphorically?  I haven't heard anyone say _random city is love_.  Maybe I just ignore it, because it doesn't make sense to me?  _Random city is heaven_ I've heard, but not _love_.

Comment: @mike [ex1](https://twitter.com/MightttBeMoosy/status/219158408992006144), [ex2](http://www.bmoremedia.com/features/bmoreloveproject051810.aspx)